# GNU Fortran - Function 'dcosd' has no IMPLICIT type

Tags: fortran, mingw, codeblocks, gfortran

I'm a newbie in Fortran coding also in GNU Fortran and Code::Blocks.

I've installed codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup on Win10 and now trying to run this piece of code from scratch:

```
program hello

implicit none

  real :: x = 0.0
  x = dcosd(x)

  write(*,*) x

end program
```

But in some reason I'm getting this Build message:

```
C:\...\Hello_Test\main.f90|7|Error: Function 'dcosd'  has no IMPLICIT type|
```

If I delete the line `implicit none` I get this message instead:

```
C:\...\Hello_Test\main.f90|5|undefined reference to `dcosd_'|
```

I'm pretty sure DCOSD is kind a standard functoun in gFortran. I tried some some solutions for "IMPLICIT type" problem, but with no result. I think the solution shuld be pretty obvious for experienced people but it eludes me.

Comment: Which GCC version are you using? If not a recent one, are you compiling with `-fdec-math`?

Comment: For future it will be best to use just `cosd`, that is new, but standard conforming. The latest version of gfortran supports it.

Comment: What happens when you include `intrinsic dcosd`?

Comment: According to build-info from C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW I'm using 'gcc version 7.3.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) '.
I cannot get where should I plae this commands. Should it be command line arguments or prebuild evente like in VS?

Comment: I use `dcosd` because of some legacy code I have to work with. Anyway `cosd` results in same error.

Comment: I tried `intrinsic dcosd` - one more error `undefined reference to 'dcosd_'` in the build messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to clarify, `dcosd()` is *not* a standard intrinsic function in Fortran. It used to be available as an extension to the standard by some compilers. Fortran 2023 brings the generic version `cosd()` as a standard intrinsic function, but modern Fortran standards do not really work too much with the specific functions like `dcosd()` and it has not been made standard.

---

GCC version 7 is quite old. `dcosd()` is recognized in your code by versions 10 and later (I tested 10, 11, 12 and 13). For versions 7-9 you need the option `-fdec-math`, mentioned by francescalus in the first comment, to enable the non-standard extension.

However, with these later versions or with the `-fdec-math` option you will get another error

```
    6 |   x = dcosd(x)
      |            1
Error: ‘x’ argument of ‘dcosd’ intrinsic at (1) must be double precision
```

That will be fixed by `double precision :: x = 0`.

Or you can change `dcosd()` to the generic `cosd()`. In that case the single precision version will be used and the code will compile with either `real` or `double precision` in GCC version 10 and later.

Comment: Not quite correct.  `cosd` was added in the Fortran 2023 standard not the 2003 standard.  I suspect a typo.  Also, note the degree trigonometric functions were added in [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html), but were hidden by the `-fdec-math` options.  Finally, `cosd` is a generic intrinsic subprogram while `dcosd` is not part of the Fortran standard, but is still provided as an extension.

Comment: @steve Just a typo. It is a coincidence that it hit a year of another standard. After all, it wasn't the only.typo in the text. I do not think I explained the difference wrongly.